# Why is norm.pdf of unscaled distribution divided by scale in scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

In Scipy documentation : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html

> The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form. To shift and/or scale the distribution use the loc and scale parameters. Specifically, norm.pdf(x, loc, scale) is identically equivalent to norm.pdf(y) / scale with y = (x - loc) / scale.

I don't get why do we divide y by scale, if we have normalized y then why do we divide the norm pdf(y) / scale again?

Even in these notes: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1178/lectureHandouts/110-normal-distribution.pdf, it seems that projection to standard normalization requires merely to subtract mean and divide by SD.

Comment: *"... it seems that projection to standard normalization requires merely to subtract mean and divide by SD."* Yes, and in scipy's implementation, the `scale` parameter *is* the standard deviation.

Comment: ya, but why do we divide the pdf by scale?

Comment: If you didn't, the integral over the real line of PDF would not be 1 (i.e. it would not be a PDF).

Answer (score 0):

Note that what Scipy documentation states does not mean you need to do anything extra to get the pdf of `x`. It just highlights what is the relationship between `pdf(x)` and `pdf(y)` where `y` is derived from the standardization of `x`.

In short, if you want to standardize `x` with mean `loc` and standard deviation `scale`, the transformation is `y=(x-loc)/scale`.

Furthermore:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

norm.pdf(a, loc= b, scale = c) = norm.pdf(a, loc= 0, scale = 1)/c
norm.cdf(a, loc= b, scale = c) = norm.cdf(a, loc= 0, scale = 1)
```

I agree with you it is confusing to have this statement in the documentation because this is a property of the distribution and transformation and not what we need to do when using `pdf`.